# How to prove $\tanh^{-1}(\sin x)=\sin^{-1}(\tan x)$

Tags: trigonometry, theorem-provers

Here's what I attempted:

$$ y =\tanh^{-1}(\sin x)$$

$$\tanh y=\sin x$$
But I don't know what to do after this. Please help me.

Comment: What are your definitions of $\sin, \sinh, \tan, \tanh$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two are not equal. Let $x = \pi/3$ for instance. Then

$$\text{arctanh}(\sin(x)) \approx 1.32$$

(per [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctanh%28sin%28pi%2F3%29%29)), while you can't even get a real-number result for the latter equation. This is because

$$\arcsin(\tan(\pi/3)) = \arcsin( \sqrt 3)$$

but the domain for arcsine (for real outputs) is $[-1,1]$. In particular, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin%28tan%28pi%2F3%29%29) approximates the answer as about $1.57 - 1.15i$.

Comment: Thank you. I was making a mistake.